# Modify ip addresses in a socks capture pcap

Tags: socks, pcap

I have a pcap capture of socks traffic. The traffic goes like -

`client_ip <-> 127.0.0.1:9050 <-> destination_ip`

Looking at pcap in wireshark, thus, shows:

```
src_ip = 127.0.0.1 
dst_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Is it possible to change src_ip and dst_ip addresses?

I tried bittwiste as:

```
bittwiste -I in.pcap -O out.pcap -T ip -p 6 -s 127.0.0.1,1.2.3.4 -d
127.0.0.1,4.3.2.1
```

But, only first record gets modified. All packets from 2nd onwards remain the same.

I also tried tcprewrite as:

```
tcprewrite --seed=325 --infile=in.pcap --outfile=out.pcap
```

This changes all src_ip & dst_ip (127.0.0.1) to the same random IP, since it finds only one (same) endpoint IP.

How can I modify src & dst ip addresses in a socks traffic capture.?

Thanks